# Há algum design pattern que possa auxiliar nesse problema?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software, ddd

Estou com um problema que me parece ser razoavelmente comum. O problema, no caso concreto, é o seguinte: o usuário quer registrar no sistema os serviços disponiveis para venda juntamente com os valores. Ao vender um serviço, o usuário quer que o serviço fique ativo para o cliente.

Finalmente, para alguns serviços há regras e propriedades específicas que o sistema precisa consultar. Um exemplo seria serviço de suporte, que tem as horas que o cliente paga por mês. Esse serviço tem uma regra específica: só pode ser realizado se as horas ainda não foram gastas no mês, e tem uma propriedade específica: o número de horas.

Agora vamos ver o problema: se o usuário cadastra os serviços manualmente, não tem como a principio o sistema saber por exemplo qual serviço é o de suporte. Na verdade, para o sistema vão ser todos iguais.  Isso porque em tese haverá uma única classe com propriedades gerais, cujas instâncias são os serviços cadastrados para venda.

Isso claramente conflita com precisar especificar regras e detalhes para tipos específicos de serviço.

Como eu disse, eu acho que isso pode ser mais comum do que parece a princípio. Eu citei um caso concreto, mas poderiamos abstrair da seguinte forma: o usuário quer cadastrar de forma personalizada alguns objetos, porém esses objetos precisam ter comportamentos específicos, com propriedades específicas e regras específicas, o que conflita com o usuário querer cadastrá-los a vontade.

Nesse sentido a solução que eu identifiquei foi a seguinte: identificar os tipos de serviço, criar uma classe para cada tipo, e no cadastro pedir para o usuário escolher o tipo, abrindo possibilidade da personalização. Aqui parece que caberia o uso de herança, mas eu sei que isso é sutil.

Fora isso pensei nos bounded contexts do DDD. Cheguei a pensar se o problema não seria o termo "Serviço" estar sendo usado em dois contextos diferentes, representando coisas diferentes. O problema é que apesar de identificar o problema, não identifiquei como lidar com a questão do "tipo do serviço".

Como isso me parece até comum, pensei se não haveria um design pattern que trata disso. Esse tipo de situação é assunto de algum design pattern? Existe uma solução conhecida e testada que dê conta desse tipo de problema?

Ou a solução que eu propus de criar uma classe para cada tipo de serviço, abstraindo suas caracteristicas principais, permitindo ao usuário escolher o tipo no cadastro seria a melhor solução?

Comment: Sem conhecer detalhes da implementação, eu acredito que seu último parágrafo é o melhor caminho.

Comment: @Renan, não dei detalhes de implementação, porque achei que a pergunta seria melhor recebida de uma forma mais genérica. Você acha que ela poderia ficar melhor dando detalhes? Além disso, com relação a implementação, só achei um problema: como eu deixaria o usuário escolher o tipo que será usado para criar o serviço, ao final? Uma enum com os tipos possíveis e então um mapeamento dos valores da enum para as classes?

Answer (score 1):

**Feature Flags**

Esse é nome do *pattern* que procura. Você pode ler mais sobre isso [nessa outra resposta do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707383/what-is-a-feature-flag), ou no Wikipedia sobre [Feature Toggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle).

Uma *Feature Flag* (ou *Feature Toggle*) é a habilidade de ativar/desativar recursos (sub-seções) do seu aplicativo facilmente:

- Através de um *rebuild*, ou
- de área interna onde páginas/características/recursos possam ser alternadas com efeito imediato.

É conveniente ter o controle de cortar ou ativar um conjunto de recursos, no caso de precisar, por exemplo, reduzir o número de consultas no BD, se a carga estiver muito alta.

Há montes de outros motivos que você iria querer usar este recurso - um dos principais é permitir a implementação contínua: publicar novidades para produção tendo o novo recurso desabilitado até que ela esteja concluído. Muitas vezes usamos o que chamamos de um 'cookie dev' para mostrar características não concluídas para a equipe do colaborador. Desta forma podemos testar recursos parcialmente concluídos já em produção. E quando essas estiverem prontos, basta ativar o recurso para que ele se torne público à todos.

Este é um simples pacote que ajuda você a fazer isso com ASP.NET MVC: https://github.com/cottsak/DevCookie

[Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/) também tem um [artigo antigo com muito mais detalhes](http://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html).

Comment: *Ativar ou desativar funcionalidades ou características específicas* não parece o mesmo conceito de *escolher uma dentre muitas formas de realizar um certo processo*.

Comment: Depende da sua implementação. Você pode facilmente fazer uma "feature" tipo "ProcessoQualquer:EnviaEmail" e por cliente vc ativa ou desativa. E no fim, essa feature será apenas um passo do seu fluxo/processo.

Answer (score 1):

## Modelagem do Código

Do ponto de vista do código, o problema soa exatamente como o *Strategy Pattern*.

Exemplo:

```
abstract class CalculoHoras {
  int calcularHoras(int mes) {
    List<Servico> servicosDoMes = carregarServicosDoMes(mes);
    int horasAPagar = calcularHorasAPagar(servicosDoMes);
    cobrarCliente(horasAPagar);
  }
  abstract int calcularHorasAPagar(List<Servico> servicosDoMes);
}
```

A partir daí, você pode criar quaisquer estratégicas para calcular as horas extendendo a classe. Então, de acordo com a configuração do sistema, você instancia uma das implementações na hora de realizar o cálculo.

Outra forma, sem usar herança, seria criar uma interface:

```
interface MetodoCalculoHorasAPagar { 
  int calcularHorasAPagar(List<Servico> servicosDoMes);
}
```

Aí você cria as implementações que desejar e consome uma delas cada vez que for realizar o cálculo:

class CalculoHoras {
      int calcularHoras(int mes, MetodoCalculoHorasAPagar metodo) {
        List servicosDoMes = carregarServicosDoMes(mes);
        int horasAPagar = metodo.calcularHorasAPagar(servicosDoMes);
        cobrarCliente(horasAPagar);
      }
    }

Observações:

- Usar delegação e interfaces é em geral uma prática melhor do que usar herança, ainda que em geral o padrão de projetos original use herança.
- Os nomes e métodos usados acima são apenas ilustrativos, use conforme o seu caso.

## Design geral

Padrões de projetos são interessantes, mas quase sempre não são uma solução por si sós, além de serem de muito baixo nível.

Pensar no design de uma solução para tornar uma funcionalidade flexível envolve pensar em variados aspectos, tais como:

- Quem vai usar tal funcionalidade
- Como ela será usada
- Flexibilidade vs Complexidade
- Segurança

E por aí vai. Só então o código passa a ser importante.

A primeira pergunta a ser feita neste contexto é: **é possível identificar um conjunto finito, limitado de possíveis estratégicas de cálculo?**

Se a resposta for afirmativa, então basta identificar e implementar tais estratégicas. Do ponto de vista dos usuários, se ele tentar realizar o cálculo sem selecionar uma estratégia, dê uma resposta visual dizendo que o resultado estará indisponível até que ele define a estratégia.

Se a reposta for negativa, então uma possível solução seria ter um conjunto de estratégicas comuns e permitir a extensão das regras. Este é um ponto complicado, pois existem várias formas de se fazer isto:

- A mais básica e manual é oferecer um serviço onde o cliente manda uma especificação e você implementa conforme ele quer. Para poucos clientes é simples, mas para muitos é uma dor de cabeça. Não é uma boa solução caso as regras variem com frequência.
- Talvez seja possível identificar as variáveis envolvidas na definição de novas regras e criar uma regra configurável via tela. Esta solução permite um pouco de flexibilidade, mas ainda assim envolve determinar tudo o que pode variar.
- Se o problema puder ser resolvido com uma fórmula matemática ou financeira e algumas variáveis de entrada, seria possível permitir ao usuário entrar tal fórmula usando algum interpretador de expressões matemáticas.
- Por fim, você pode permitir que os usuários contribuam com regras via código. Você pode se aproveitar do fato de que existem várias linguagens dinâmicas que rodam dentro da JVM de forma segura e permitir que o usuário escreva, por exemplo, uma função JavaScript num campo do sistema e você executa tal função no servidor. Esta solução é interessante de os seus clientes são da área de TI ou possuem setores de TI administrando os sistemas da empresa. Na verdade, você pode implementar esta solução para você mesmo, pois desta forma você poderia escrever a regra, colocar o script no banco do cliente por alguma tela administrativa ou script SQL e ter uma nova função no sistema sem ter que gerar uma nova versão.